# How to enforce login with password from P4V client?

Tags: authentication, perforce, p4v

How do I prompt a third input for password from this P4V visual client?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to make your **personal** server ask for a password? Or are you asking about the difference between your **personal** server and a **remote** server?

Comment: I am asking how to make my personal server (which reside on my machine and is a clone of a remote server) ask for a password.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a password for your user, that password will be required for login in the future.  By default a login session lasts 12 hours.

As the administrator of a server (this includes a personal server on your own machine), you can require all users to set passwords and require the client to use a login prompt rather than a plaintext `P4PASSWD` by setting the `security` counter to 3: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.superuser.html

Comment: I have a personal server on my machine (that is a clone of remote server) and it has a user with a password. But it never asks for a password. As you can see there is no provision of inputting a password at all and anyone logged in to my machine can login to my personal server just with the username.

Comment: Cloning the files from the remote server does not clone user information (including passwords), so I'm pretty sure your personal server doesn't have a password set.  Connect to your personal server and run `p4 passwd` (or the P4V equivalent, there's probably a "Set Password..." menu option).